# What are the best way to write regular expression for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have this ruby on rails regular expression which look like this

```
str = "1,890.89"
```

I want to convert this to.

```
=> 1890.89 # Removing the comma
```

So I created a regular expression something like this.

```
[/[0-9\.]+/i]
```

and then add to the string something like this

```
str[/[0-9\.]+/i]
```

Expecting the results

```
=> 1890.89
```

but the results is like this.

```
=> 1
```

the remaining digit and point are not included.

Just so you know I tried the regex here
[image]

I'm Using

```
ruby '2.4.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
```

Comment: Why do you need regex?

Comment: I need regex as I am scraping a price and put it on my database without the comma

Comment: This is a two step process. Matching comma separated number then taking comma off the match.

Comment: you mean split first then combine again.

Comment: Use `str.delete(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @revo you need to do two steps as following to remove comma then join results:

```
str.scan(/[0-9\.]+/i).join()
```

Or you can do it without regex if you just need to remove the comma:

```
str.gsub(',', '')
```

Comment: Why do we need gsub? Simple `delete` method would do the Job.

Comment: @Rajagopalan it can be done in both ways, but `delete` will remove all occurrences of string  but `gsub` gives you more control to include regex to remove string in specific scenarios (first occurrence, all occurrences)

Comment: there's also currency symbol and currency sign

Comment: I know but for the given condition delete is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a string and you want remove comma, you don't need regular expression, simply use `delete` method

```
 str.delete(',')
```

Comment: actually the string is from the website i am scraping

Comment: @Ruel Nopal So what's the problem? Call the delete method upon the string object which you receiving from web.